# Viewing PDF in Linux remotely

Tags: linux, terminal, pdf

I'm trying to view a PDF remotely while in my university's Linux Cluster (which uses Red Hat). The problem is, I don't know what PDF viewers are pre-installed. I tried installing okular with

```
yum install okular
```

But I get

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, priorities, product-id, search-disabled-repos, 
subscription-manager
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

Is there a way to see what PDF viewers I already have while ssh'ed remotely into the cluster, and (assuming none are pre-installed), is there any easy way to install a new PDF viewer without yum or sudo?

Comment: last resort is ghostview, but is you don;t have pdftotext you probably don't have `gv` either.

Comment: No, unfortunately it returns "gv: command not found..."

Comment: What do you mean by remotely?   where is the PDF, where is your display connected?

Comment: I mean remotely as in on the cluster. I ssh into the cluster, run a Julia code, and then produce a plot that saves as pdf. I want to view the pdf while ssh'ed into the cluster.

Comment: sshfs seems like a possible solution,  just connect to the cluster using your file manager and open the pdf

Answer (score 3):

In order to know what the default association is, you can run:

```
$ xdg-open filename
```

Or, by mime-type:

```
$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf
```

You can also view pdf files directly from your browser. All major browsers do it.

Comment: I tried that, and I get "xdg-open: no method available for opening filename". Also, how could I view the pdf from my browser if the pdf is on the remote cluster?

Comment: I added another method. If that fails too you might want to try to open it with the browser. Firefox can open a PDF, for example.

Comment: There are lot of methods to see the PDF. For example, you could use `sshfs` or `ssh` with port forwarding and then run `python3 -m http.server <port>` to see the directory, ... But that's another question. What did `xdg-mime` return?

Comment: It said my file "is not in the form 'minor/major'". Perhaps it's due to my naming convention? The full file is called Entropy_at_pc\|_L\:20_\|_p_c\:0.1_\|_T\:20_\|_Samples\:50_\|_States\:1000_\|_Elapsed\:0.006_hours_20210102-160549.pdf.  Could it be that some of the characters are causing it trouble? Also, I am still unsure how to open a pdf in my browser if the pdf is on the remote cluster. Really, I just wanted a quick way to view some of saved matplotlib plots I made while ssh'ed into my school's cluster.

Comment: Then you can just do a `scp` (same credentials as the `ssh`) to copy those files to your local machine. You can rename it locally as something saner (the name is pretty weird).

Comment: @GAD3R Just updated it

Comment: I'd prefer a way to open them remotely, rather than scp'ing every time I generate a plot. Also, unfortunately I cannot change the name (accept for minor syntax things); it has to be that way so I can see all the necessary parameters.

Comment: firefox cannot open PDFs.  that's a plugin,.

Comment: @jasen your comment is outdated. It's been built-in from 2012 onwards. Starting around version 82 (I don't remember exactly) it even lets you fill forms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF.js#History_and_Application.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to be root to perform this command.

You need to run this command as privileged user:

```
sudo yum install okular
```

If you have a pdf viewer already installed use:

```
xdg-open file.pdf
```

If any pdf viewer is not installed you can view the pdf file in your terminal:

```
pdftotext file.pdf -
```

With your browser:

```
sensible-browser file.pdf
```

To open your file through `ssh` you need to pass `-X` (Enables X11 forwarding) option then you can open it in your local machine:

```
ssh -X
```

Comment: I am not in the sudoers file

Comment: I tried xdg-open and it said "is not in the form 'minor/major'" and then said "xdg-open: no method available for opening file.pdf". I also cannot use pdftotext as the pdf I am trying to view is a saved matplotlib graph.